# How to define an alias for user function in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a way how to define some kind of alias in Excel. Let's say I have this long function to categorize/tag every line in home expenses list:

> =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Curry",$F2)),"Curry",IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"LIDL","TESCO","ALBERT","BILLA"},$F2))),"Groceries",IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"FITINN","GM
>   ELECTRONIC"},$F2))),"Fun","")))

It simply checks neighboring cell and fills a tag into a current cell. Now let's say this function is hundred lines long, so I do not want to put it on every line in a sheet. I'd like to create an alias named 'tag' and put just =tag in every cell. How do I achieve something like that?

Comment: What exactly is the reason you don't want to copy this formula to other cells?

Comment: Try a UDF instead

Comment: Well, if I'll have 10k lines in the sheet it will make the file inconveniently large, but mostly I'll have to copy the formula over each time I'll add another tag in ALL cells, instead of editing it in one place.

Comment: I thought this is UDF? Sorry, not much experience with Excel, I'm more bash-scripting-type of guy...:-/

Answer (score 1):

You need to unleash some VBA to take care of this.  Basically you define your function, "TAG" in your case, using the VBA editor, and then attach the resulting module to your spreadsheet.  Then you can use "=TAG(...)" in the Excel formula bar as if it were a builtin.

See [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel) for guidance.  The magic phrase to google for is User Defined Function.

Answer (score 1):

Use tables.

Highlight the entire rectangle of cells, including your header row, choose "Insert Table", and turn it into a table.

Then replace your mention of F2 with `[@ColumnTitle]` where "ColumnTitle" is the title of the column of F. [ColumnTitle] refers to the whole column, [@ColumnTitle] refers to that column's cell in the current row.

Once you replace the entire row with a formula that doesn't use "A1" notation that's the same for every cell in that row, then [the formula is stored exactly once regardless of how many rows are in the table](http://exceltables.com/remembering-table-formulas/). If you change it in any cell, it changes for the entire column, your maintenance has just eased considerably and your formula is more readable.

And by the way, you can use UDFs in tables, too, so you can have a formula of `=MyUDF([ColumnTitleA],[@ColumnTitleA],Offset([@ColumnTitleB],-1,0))` and it will pass all of the data in A, the cell in A for the current row, and the cell in B for the previous row.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the following to be a bit easier on the eye:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$8,MATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($E$2:$E$8,$A$2))),0))
```

I've tested it with the following setup - the formula above is in cell **A5**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll consider that, even though I prefer to have the formula self-contained with everything in one place, but your solution would be nicely editable. But that won't help with my original question.